# Aligning multiple-line th/td centered

Tags: html, css, browser, html-table

How do I align an HTML table header's contents to be centered but line up aligned left when there are multiple lines?

To illustrate:

```
<th style="text-align:center;">This table header will span multiple rows because 
I've set a width on it</th>
```

Instead of this result:

This table header
  will span multiple
rows because I've set
      a width on it

I want this result:

This table header
  will span multiple
  rows because I've
  set a width on it

Or something similar. I have tried putting a `div` inside the `th` with all combinations of floating and aligning but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<th style="text-align:left; padding-left:15px;"></th>
```

Comment: This might work but I'd prefer a more generic solution. Like there are many columns, all with different widths

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
th { 
padding:any;
text-align: left;
width: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your text in an other element that is align left.

```
<th style="text-align:center;"><span style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">This table header will span multiple rows because 
I've set a width on it</span></th>
```

Comment: This just aligns it left (in Firefox anyway)

Comment: @user982119 I tried it in IE, it aligns left when there's a lot of text, else if aligns center.